# Serialize JSON date as yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss:fffzzzz without colon in the timezone

Tags: c#, json.net, asp.net-web-api2

I am using NewtonSoft.JSON to serialize my object to JSON.  I have a requirement where the datetime format has to be 2017-05-06T11:59:37:012-0500.  I've passed in my own datetime format to get it to pass as this 2017-05-06T11:59:37:012-05:00.  However I am uncertain how to remove the colon in the time zone.

Here is how you can convert it, but I need something where I can actually work with the string directly.

```
var postDataSerialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(postData, new IsoDateTimeConverter() { DateTimeFormat = "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss:fffzzzz" });
```

Comment: You could create your own [custom `JsonConverter`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm) similar to [`IsoDateTimeConverter`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Converters/IsoDateTimeConverter.cs) with the necessary formatting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way to avoid this colon just by adjusting some parameter value. `IsoDateTimeConverter` [uses](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/c89b5b45aa1663d0f38ef230e6c01590a5dec9f5/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Converters/IsoDateTimeConverter.cs#L93) .Net `DateTime` custom format feature, and the [colon is hardcoded](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/e458f8df6ded689323d4bd1a2a725ad32668aaec/mscorlib/system/globalization/datetimeformat.cs#L743) for the `zzz` custom format.

Therefore you have to implement the desired formatting yourself, which can be done by providing a custom `JsonConverter`. The custom converter may look like this:

```
public class NoColonIsoDateTimeConverter : IsoDateTimeConverter
{
    public NoColonIsoDateTimeConverter()
    {
        DateTimeFormat = "yyyy'-'MM'-'ddTHH':'mm':'ss':'fffzzz";
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (value is DateTime)
        {
            var dateTime = (DateTime)value;
            var text = dateTime.ToString(DateTimeFormat);
            text = text.Remove(text.Length - 3, 1);
            writer.WriteValue(text);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new JsonSerializationException("Unexpected value when converting date. Expected DateTime");
        }
    }
}
```

Demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/79AuZs